# How to get external display information after choosing use as separate as display via screen mirroring on MacOS?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-graphics, airplay

I would like to get some information of the connected display such as vendor number, eisaId, … after connecting the external display via “screen mirroring” -> “use as Separate Display”

When the same display was connected through HDMI port or extend mode in screen mirroring, the information is not identical:

HDMI

Other display found - ID: 19241XXXX, Name: YYYY (Vendor: 19ZZZ, Model: 57WWW)

Screen mirroring - extend mode

Other display found - ID: 41288XX, Name: AAA (Vendor: 163ZYYBBB, Model: 16ZZWWYYY)

I tried to get display information with the below method.

```
func configureDisplays() {
    var onlineDisplayIDs = [CGDirectDisplayID](repeating: 0, count: 16)
    var displayCount: UInt32 = 0
    guard CGGetOnlineDisplayList(16, &onlineDisplayIDs, &displayCount) == .success else {
      os_log("Unable to get display list.", type: .info)
      return
    }
    for onlineDisplayID in onlineDisplayIDs where onlineDisplayID != 0 {
      let name = DisplayManager.getDisplayNameByID(displayID: onlineDisplayID)
      let id = onlineDisplayID
      let vendorNumber = CGDisplayVendorNumber(onlineDisplayID)
      let modelNumber = CGDisplayModelNumber(onlineDisplayID)
      let serialNumber = CGDisplaySerialNumber(onlineDisplayID)
      if !DEBUG_SW, DisplayManager.isAppleDisplay(displayID: onlineDisplayID) { 
        let appleDisplay = AppleDisplay(id, name: name, vendorNumber: vendorNumber, modelNumber: modelNumber, serialNumber: serialNumber, isVirtual: isVirtual, isDummy: isDummy)
        os_log("Apple display found - %{public}@", type: .info, "ID: \(appleDisplay.identifier), Name: \(appleDisplay.name) (Vendor: \(appleDisplay.vendorNumber ?? 0), Model: \(appleDisplay.modelNumber ?? 0))")
      } else {
        let otherDisplay = OtherDisplay(id, name: name, vendorNumber: vendorNumber, modelNumber: modelNumber, serialNumber: serialNumber, isVirtual: isVirtual, isDummy: isDummy)
        os_log("Other display found - %{public}@", type: .info, "ID: \(otherDisplay.identifier), Name: \(otherDisplay.name) (Vendor: \(otherDisplay.vendorNumber ?? 0), Model: \(otherDisplay.modelNumber ?? 0))")
      }
    }
  }
```

Can we have the same display information when connect with an external display via HDMI port and extend mode in Screen Mirroring?